# How to automatically log-in to remote MySQL instance via ssh behind another host?

Tags: ssh, proxy, alias, bash-alias

I have an alias set up to ssh to a remote machine through a proxy ...

```
alias sshcmd='ssh -t davea@proxy ssh destmachine'
```

but I want to set up an alias where I ssh into the remote machine and then automatically log in to MySql.  However, this command doesn't work ...

```
alias mysqlremotecmd="ssh -t davea@proxy 'ssh destmachine mysql -uusername -ppassword -hmysqldomain.com db_sid'"
```

But this command just hangs.  What is the proper way to build the alias to automatically log me in to the remote MySQL instance?

Comment: What happens when you leave out the inner set of quotes?

Comment: Same thing -- the command just hangs

Comment: try giving the 2nd ssh command a `-t` as well

Comment: Yup, adding -t caused everything to work.